# What happens to %rax after an empty return statement in a void function?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

My understanding is that, if a void function is executed *without* a return statement, then %rax will still store whatever is returned from the previous non-void function.

That is, if:

```
int a(int param){
    return param;
}

void b(){
}

int main(){
    a(5);
    b();
    return 1;
}
```

Then after main finishes execution but before returning, the value stored in %rax will be 5.

My question is, what happens if b has an empty return statement?
That is,

```
void b(){
    return;
}
```

Does that clear out %rax? Or does %rax still retain its previous value still?

Comment: There no point in clearing `%rax` for a void return since no one is supposed to look at it.  There's also no telling what its previous value would be as the compiled code could use it for anything.

Comment: This is a contrived example, sure, but I remember getting a bug once where, because one of the branches in an int function did not have a return statement, the value that got returned was erroneously actually from the previously called function. Should we not, then, for the sake of robustness, clear out %rax whenever possible to avoid bugs like that?

Comment: No, clearing this register for robustness is not what we want.  What we want is a compile-time error for failing to return a value, so we can realize and fix the bug.  I believe modern C compilers will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then %rax will still store whatever is returned from the previous non-void function.

No, your understanding is wrong.

When RAX doesn't hold a return value (void or FP functions), it's a call-clobbered register like RCX or RSI for example.  Read the calling convention docs or look at compiler output.

And BTW, an explicit `return` statement vs. reaching the `}` at the bottom is completely irrelevant.  (Except that falling off the end of a *non*-`void` function is UB, and some compilers will compile that to a `ud2` illegal instruction.)

> Then after main finishes execution but before returning, the value stored in %rax will be 5.

That is 100% implementation detail; a compiler can do anything it wants with registers within a function, like use RAX to evaluate non-function-call expressions.  The calling convention only nails down the boundaries between functions.

Comment: Falling off a non-void function is only undefined behaviour if the return value is used by the caller (cf. ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.9.1 ¶12).

Comment: @fuz: Thanks.  Maybe the `ud2` in that case from clang (IIRC) was only in C++.  I'm pretty sure I've seen a `ud2` in the function itself. I often have Godbolt in C++ mode.  (This question isn't tagged C or C++ so we don't know which applies.)